# GROUP BY in ContentResolver.query

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

I need to use GROUP BY or similar in ContentResolver.query().

For previous Android versions in the selection field put something like this: "*1) GROUP BY 1, (2*", that is, the brackets themselves were closed. Its not works in android 10, where selection field looks like this: "*WHERE ((is_pending=0) AND (is_trashed=0) AND (volume_name IN ( 'external_primary' , '12f2-2310' ))) AND ((1) GROUP BY 1, (2))*" , i.e. on late AND.

What else can be done?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use GROUP BY or similar in ContentResolver.query()"

There is no requirement for a `ContentProvider` that you did not write to support arbitrary SQL.

> For previous Android versions in the selection field put something like this..."

There is no guarantee that this will work across all Android devices, as device manufacturers can and do change various system-supplied `ContentProvider` implementations.

> What else can be done?

Do the calculations and data manipulation client-side, as you would need to do when accessing any other data source (e.g., REST-style Web service) that you do not control.